# Bootstrap calender not closing on clicking outside in iPad

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, calendar, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angularjs with bootstrap. Calender is displaying after clicking on input field but not get closed if I clicked outside of calender. Its working fine for Desktop web browsers **but not working in iPad**.

My code for calender is

```
<input type="text" ng-mouseover="clickHover18=true"
 ng-mouseleave="clickHover18=false" ng-focus="clickActive18=true"
 ng-blur="clickActive18=false" class="cal-control scheduleMargin r3InputField"
 id="selectupgradeEvcTime" datepicker-popup="{{format}}"
 placeholder="MM/DD/YY" ng-model="$parent.dateSelection" is-open="opened"
 min="minDate" max="'2025-12-31'" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
 date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="'true'"
 close-text="Close" ng-keypress-disabled /> 
<span class="cal-icon cal-icon-date dataMargin">
</span>
```

Please suggest me solution for iPad.

Comment: I imagine that's nothing to do with the calender's click events, you'll need to put a click event on the document if you watch catch it... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element?rq=1

Comment: @JamieHutber not working still

Comment: You'll need to add a lot more of the code :) Aka a working example or the JS

Comment: HI..., your problem could be you used  mouse-events , but iPad ,android doesn't support it. that's why  you are not getting close .  ng-mouseover="clickHover18=true" 
 ng-mouseleave="clickHover18=false" . can give here jsFiddle

Comment: i was also met this situation

Comment: @J.SRINIVasan same issue I am facing for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28961350/click-event-not-working-properly-in-ipad-with-angularjs