# click event not working properly in iPad with angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ipad, jquery-events

I created angularjs directive for attribute `globalEvents` and added to body element. Please find below code:

```
<body globalEvents>
<div id="container" ng-controller="appController">
```

Angularjs code :

```
    angularApp.directive('globalEvents', [function() {
        return {
            restrict:"A",
            replace:true,
            link:function(scope,elm,attr) {
                elm.on('click', function (e) {
                   // not working in iPad
                }
            }
       }
   }
```

Above click event not working in iPad unless and until I add ng-click attribute to container div `(id="container")`

```
<div ng-click="" id="container" ng-controller="appController">
```

I don't understand reason behind this. But this is not solution for this issue. Please help me

I am using AngularJS v1.2.15

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use `angular.element()`

```
 angular.element(elm).on('click touchstart', function (e) {
 //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-----------^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

As you are binding a jqLite's event to a raw DOM node `elm`, instead you should wrap it with `angular.element` to create a jquery object to attach a jqlite event on it.

[Docs for angular.element()](https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.15/docs/api/ng/function/angular.element)

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But the code that I used is working fine in desktop browsers but not working in iPad

Comment: @TusharAhirrao i guess you need to use `'click touchstart'` event too.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try this and let you know here